# Game won't open when the virtual space have debug mode

Tags: android, debugging, virtual

I have a virtual space app. When I add a game in it, it opens and works perfectly. But when I enable debug mode `android:debuggable="true"`
in AndroidManifest.xml, no game opens. How could I fix this?
Thanks in advance.

I tried enabling debug mode from classes.dex but it is like there is no debug mode.